# Strange condition in a while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I was looking through some exam tasks to my informatics course and came across a confusing line of code in one of them:

```
while(a % b) {
//body of the loop
}
```

I was sure that the condition should be of type `bool`however the modulo operator `%` applied to two integers return a remainder of the division which is of type `int`. I have tried to run this code and it works, but I am still puzzled how it works. What am I missing in the properties of the `while`-statement?

Sorry if it is a not so clever question, haven't been into informatics for a while.

In case it is necessary, here's the whole body of the function I have taken it from:

```
int foo (int a, int b){
    int t;
    while(a % b) {
        t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t % b;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Zero is false. That which is not false is true.

Comment: Basically, the condition is "while `b` does not divide `a`". What you show is the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) for calculating greatest common divisor.

Comment: @stefan as I mentioned it is a part of an exam task. Another task is to say what mathematical operation this function refers to.

Comment: @DavidO, [Not strictly true](http://markshroyer.com/2012/06/c-both-true-and-false/), but under normal conditions, yes :)

Comment: @DmitryKazakov, Now that you know how it works, please don't use `int`s as `bool`s. Just compare to 0 explicitly.

Comment: @chris do you mean it is not a good style of programming?

Comment: Integers store numbers. I, for one, don't think of numbers as being `true` or `false` immediately. If I see `if (something)`, my first thought is that `something` is a `bool` or something with an obvious boolean condition, such as a pointer. If it's not one of those, it takes me a little bit of extra precious time to figure out that okay, it's an `int`, and `int`s are `true` when not 0, so what does the condition actually mean? Oh, it's testing that `a % b` isn't zero. Also more of a chance to accidentally reverse the condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If any number type is used in a boolean context, a non-zero number becomes `true` and zero becomes `false`. The conversion is implicit, so you don't have to do anything special for it to happen as seen in the above example.

Answer (score 2):

The integer result is implicitly converted to a bool, following the rule that a non-zero value is true (including negative).

The following would be more clear: `while((a % b) != 0)`

Answer (score 0):

The Loop continues to run as long as the condition is met, the condition can be a Boolean however it can also be any number, in this case '0' evaluates to 'false' and anything other than '0' evaluates to 'true'.

Your loop will continue to run until the result of the modulo operation is '0', ie when b is a multiple of a!

Cheers!